# More efficient way of screening KeyCodes on KeyDown Event

Tags: c#, events, key, keydown, keycode

I'm trying to fire an event perform some work when the user tries to enter only **useful data** into a form-field using the KeyDown event. But, I keep getting false alarms because the KeyDown event works for just any key!

I'm trying not to make the event fire for buttons such as "Alt, Control, Shift, Esc, the F-keys, etc." What's the best way of doing this?

What I have so far is this:

```
    private void formControl_KeyModified(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode != Keys.Shift && e.KeyCode != Keys.CapsLock && e.KeyCode != Keys.Tab && e.KeyCode != Keys.Escape &&
            e.KeyCode != Keys.Insert && e.KeyCode != Keys.Home && e.KeyCode != Keys.End && e.KeyCode != Keys.PageUp &&
            e.KeyCode != Keys.PageDown && e.KeyCode != Keys.Up && e.KeyCode != Keys.Down && e.KeyCode != Keys.Left &&
            e.KeyCode != Keys.Right && e.KeyCode != Keys.Control && e.KeyCode != Keys.Alt && e.KeyCode != Keys.NumLock &&
            e.KeyCode != Keys.Insert && e.KeyCode != Keys.None && e.KeyCode != Keys.PrintScreen && e.KeyCode != Keys.Help &&
            e.KeyCode != Keys.ControlKey && e.KeyCode != Keys.ShiftKey && e.KeyCode != Keys.Sleep && e.KeyCode != Keys.LWin &&
            e.KeyCode != Keys.RWin && e.KeyCode != Keys.RMenu && e.KeyCode != Keys.LMenu && e.KeyCode != Keys.LShiftKey &&
            e.KeyCode != Keys.RShiftKey && e.KeyCode != Keys.Pause && e.KeyCode != Keys.F1 && e.KeyCode != Keys.F2 &&
            e.KeyCode != Keys.F3 && e.KeyCode != Keys.F4 && e.KeyCode != Keys.F5 && e.KeyCode != Keys.F6 && e.KeyCode != Keys.F7 &&
            e.KeyCode != Keys.F8 && e.KeyCode != Keys.F9 && e.KeyCode != Keys.F10 && e.KeyCode != Keys.F11 && e.KeyCode != Keys.F12 &&
            e.KeyCode != Keys.L)
        {
             // Do some work...
        }
    }
```

However, that doesn't quite seem like the best way to handle this to me. **Again, I'm just trying to get keys for the characters that could be entered into a textbox** (such as 213135udf!@#%@!#@#%15nfaosdf~!@}{:?>, and so on)! Any help at all will be appreciated, thanks!

Sincerely,
Isaac D.

(Edited for clarity and quality)

Comment: Can you write your if() for 'useful data'?

Comment: Aren't you going about this a bit backwards? Why not just handle TextChanged and if something the user has pressed has resulted in a change in the text in the textbox, then what they pressed was "useful".

Comment: @Shibumi - Not at all. Control.TextChanged won't work in my case because I'm using databinding with Binding.Format and Binding.Parse. Whenever the form loads, TextChanged is triggered because the controls pull data from the database and fill the control's value and then are evaluated, giving a faux pas. Also, since the form controls are within a TabControl, whenever the tabControl's SelectedIndexChanged is triggered (when changing tabs), TextControl is triggered again. So, the TextChanged event can't have that use in this case because it would detect everything as modified.

Comment: @Daniel Actually, what I did is screen for both useful data and unuseful data. It only worked when screening for both. So, I validated for the normal a-z, A-Z, 0-9, symbols, and characters, but I also excluded the F keys, many of the function keys, the Alt modifiers, and Ctrl + V modifiers from the result. That ended up being the most functional and secure.

Comment: That seems to be a case where you would specifically bind to that event when you knew it was relevant. Only bind to the event when databinding is complete. Unbind before tab changes and re-bind afterward. All of that, to me, is still preferable to all of that key code checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle the [KeyPress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx) event of the form. The mentioned event take a [KeyPressEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.aspx) as its arguments parameter.

Use the [Char.IsLetterOrDigit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.isletterordigit%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) function to check the value of the [KeyPressEventArgs.KeyChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.keychar.aspx) property.

```
private void form_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
{

     if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(e.KeyChar)) {}
     else { e.Handled = false; }

}
```

---

**EDIT:**

You can also try to make a list of your accepted `Char` values, then check if the preseed character is included in it:

```
private void form_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
{

     List<Char> charList = new List<Char>;
     charList.AddRange(new Char[] { 'a', 'b' ... });

     if (charList.Contains(e.KeyChar)) {}
     else { e.Handled = false; }

}
```

### You may need to consider combining both ways or even more to fulfill your requirements.

Comment: Yes, I did go there, but their example isn't very helpful -- with that example they're selecting for just the numbers along the top and in the numberpad of the keyboard, so they can do a range. But, I not only need the alphanumeric characters, but all of the symbols and everything. So, I was racking my brain to try to think up a better solution.

Comment: @Isaac: I have edited my answer. You may find something usefull in the appended section.

Answer (score 2):

You could throw all values into a [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) and check if the KeyCode is in the set.

```
var invalidKeys = new HashSet<Keys> { Keys.Shift, Keys.CapsLock, Keys.Tab, ... Keys.L };
if (!invalidKeys.Contains(e.KeyCode))
{
    // Do some work...
}
```

Or alternatively, since you're checking for equality, you could just throw all that into a switch statement.

```
switch (e.KeyCode)
{
case Keys.Shift:
case Keys.CapsLock:
case Keys.Tab:
// ...
case Keys.L:
    break;
default:
    // Do some work...
    break;
}
```

Comment: Hmm... The Switch case isn't as readable to others because there are a _lot_ of invalid keys to enter... (I'm still trying to figure out which Keycode is the one for the left and right "Alt" keys on the keyboard). But the hashset seems interesting, though Let me give that a try and get back to you.

Comment: Your hashkey solution ended up working out the best. :-) I screened for valid and invalid keys, and it works well. Thanks for your help, Jeff Mercado!

Answer (score 2):

you can for example (there are many good attempts) check [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.aspx) for help on the `Char` class where you can use methods like [IsLetterOrDigit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cay4xx2f.aspx) or other functions. Now I could not recognise if you are using Windows Forms? If so, use a simple cast like `(char)e.KeyCode` to get the char.

Example:

```
private void formControl_KeyModified(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    char c = (char)e.KeyCode;
    if (Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)) {
        // useful
    }
    // might add more checks
    // else if (Char.IsPunctuation(c)) ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is WinForms development. This is interesting -- so you're saying that I should check for the char of every keycode for each keyboard character that's unnecessary?

Comment: You should not throw away what you don't need, more just take what you need. You can try to set `e.Handled = true;` when you want to not handle the input.

Comment: I ended up using e.SuppressKeyPress on those I didn't want also. I went with Jeff's suggestion, but yours had the same logic, and thank you for suggesting it!

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned with the execution time of the if statement, create a SortedList of the Key values and check if the SortedList contains your key.

A possibly better solution is to use the Forms TextBox "TextChanged" event rather than using the KeyDown event.

Comment: For my purposes, the TextChanged method isn't going to work -- I'm trying to detect when the form controls have been modified by the user entering data or choosing a different item in a drop-down on a calendar or combobox. However, I have Binding.Parse and Binding.Format on each control that changes the data into something else and a tab control that causes these to validate very time the tab is changed. So, if I used TextChanged then as soon as the form load it's going to fire this event since B.Parse and B.Format are validated OnLoad and on SelectIndexChanged of the TabControl, unfort. :-/

Comment: Is the SortedList solution sort of like Jeff Mercado's Hash solution??

Comment: Yes, SortedList and Hash are almost the same, he posted while I was editing my answer. :-)

Comment: Well, thanks a lot for posting yours. :-) I'm excited to learn anything new, and thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Like @Daniel states in his comment, perhaps white-listing the valid keys is preferable than black-listing all those that are of no interest to you. So if, let's say, you are interested only in letter keys and numbers, you could do it just like it is described in [the msdn Keys example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx)

```
if(e.KeyCode > Keys.NumPad0 && e.KeyCode < Keys.NumPad9 ||
   e.KeyCode > Keys.D0 && e.KeyCode < Keys.D9 ||
   e.KeyCode > Keys.A && e.KeyCode < Keys.Z) {

    //do useful stuff here
}
```