# Can't use ||(or) to Keys

Tags: c#, key, keycode

I want to run a command when space or enter back is pressed.

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space || Keys.Enter )
        {
            //something
        }
```

This is what I expected, but `C#` doesn't allow me to use || to Keys, any ideas?

Comment: `if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space || Keys.Enter )` => `if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space || e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter )` The || evaluates conditional logic, so both sides need to evaluate to a bool. So in short `e.KeyCode == Keys.Space` does, but ` Keys.Enter` doesn't.

Comment: I'd suggest reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983727/more-efficient-way-of-screening-keycodes-on-keydown-event .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong.
Note the C# is a *programming language* not *human* language. Though you can say "KeyCode is either space or enter", the correct syntax for c# is to say "either KeyCode equals space, or keycode equals enter":

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space || e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
```

Comment: Great answer as well as explaining to the OP why.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space || e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter )
    {
        //something
    }
```

You need to repeat the `e.KeyCode ==` part

Comment: Why does the OP `need to repeat the e.KeyCode == part`, explanation is definitely useful in understanding the issue and how your solution addresses it.

Answer (score 2):

Proper code is:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space || e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter )
{
    //something
}
```

The If statement is treated by the compiler as

```
if (<condition-1> || <condition-2>) { /*sth*/ }
```

*condition-1 or condition-2*

Edit: If you want to check for multiple values in a more human-readable way, try an extension method.

Afaik: `System.Windows.Forms.Keys` doesn't work as binary flags. It means even `Keys.Space | Keys.Enter` won't work.

Comment: `Afaik: System.Windows.Forms.Keys doesn't work as binary flags.` It does but only for modifier keys (`Ctrl` etc).

Comment: `contition-1 or contition-1` isn't right, it's `contition-1 orelse contition-2`, that is miss-leading. IMHO, you *could* remove that to exclude confusion.

Comment: `contition-1 or contition-1` is typo, it should be `condition-1 or condition-2`. I'll fix that.